# How to document field with dash with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Given an object definition that I'm not allowed to modify:

```
let a = {"a-b" : 5};
```

How can I add JSDoc over it ?

I tried

```
/**
* @type {{"a-b": number}}
*/
```

But WebStorm tells me that this is not valid JSDoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it's a topic which hasn't been resolved yet and still is in-progress.

I'd suggest to use class comments:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object}
 * @property {number} a-b
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid way to document namepaths with special chanracters - see http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html, **Namepaths of objects with special characters in the name**. But WebStorm doesn't yet support it - see [WEB-18032](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18032)